# Angular6: Error: StaticInjectorError(AppModule)[[object Object]]

Tags: angular6

I have searched a lot about this error and nothing was useful, this kind of error usually angular tells you what is the object that lacks a provider, however this time it's giving that StaticInjectorError(AppModule)[[**object Object**]], so I couldn't figure it out.

In my app, I have separate modules:

1. appModule
2. expensesModule
3. accountsmodule

each of them has a routing module
Indeed, I am using lazyloading to route across modules.
The account-routing-module contains:

```
const routes: Routes = [
      {
        path: '',
        component: AccountsComponent,
        canActivate: [AuthGuardService],
        resolve: {
          data:{
            AccountsResolver
          }
        }
      }
    ];

@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forChild(routes)],
  exports: [RouterModule],
  providers: [
    AccountsResolver
  ]

})
export class AccountsRoutingModule {
}
```

when I access the accountscomponent, the following error appears:

> 

```
ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): Error: StaticInjectorError(AppModule)[[object Object]]: 
  StaticInjectorError(Platform: core)[[object Object]]: 
    NullInjectorError: No provider for [object Object]!
Error: StaticInjectorError(AppModule)[[object Object]]: 
  StaticInjectorError(Platform: core)[[object Object]]: 
    NullInjectorError: No provider for [object Object]!
    at NullInjector.push../node_modules/@angular/core/fesm5/core.js.NullInjector.get (vendor.js:53611)
    at resolveToken (vendor.js:53850)
    at tryResolveToken (vendor.js:53795)
    at StaticInjector.push../node_modules/@angular/core/fesm5/core.js.StaticInjector.get (vendor.js:53690)
    at resolveToken (vendor.js:53850)
    at tryResolveToken (vendor.js:53795)
    at StaticInjector.push../node_modules/@angular/core/fesm5/core.js.StaticInjector.get (vendor.js:53690)
    at resolveNgModuleDep (vendor.js:60745)
    at NgModuleRef_.push../node_modules/@angular/core/fesm5/core.js.NgModuleRef_.get (vendor.js:61433)
    at resolveNgModuleDep (vendor.js:60745)
    at NullInjector.push../node_modules/@angular/core/fesm5/core.js.NullInjector.get (vendor.js:53611)
    at resolveToken (vendor.js:53850)
    at tryResolveToken (vendor.js:53795)
    at StaticInjector.push../node_modules/@angular/core/fesm5/core.js.StaticInjector.get (vendor.js:53690)
    at resolveToken (vendor.js:53850)
    at tryResolveToken (vendor.js:53795)
    at StaticInjector.push../node_modules/@angular/core/fesm5/core.js.StaticInjector.get (vendor.js:53690)
    at resolveNgModuleDep (vendor.js:60745)
    at NgModuleRef_.push../node_modules/@angular/core/fesm5/core.js.NgModuleRef_.get (vendor.js:61433)
    at resolveNgModuleDep (vendor.js:60745)
    at resolvePromise (polyfills.js:3136)
    at resolvePromise (polyfills.js:3093)
    at polyfills.js:3195
    at ZoneDelegate.push../node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js.ZoneDelegate.invokeTask (polyfills.js:2743)
    at Object.onInvokeTask (vendor.js:56325)
    at ZoneDelegate.push../node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js.ZoneDelegate.invokeTask (polyfills.js:2742)
    at Zone.push../node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js.Zone.runTask (polyfills.js:2510)
    at drainMicroTaskQueue (polyfills.js:2917)
defaultErrorLogger @ vendor.js:54201
```

but when I comment out the AccountsResolver in the resolve, the component loads normally without any error.
I don't know if the error is because of the AccountsResolver which implements Resolve, or because of something else. Any idea will be appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 12):

I know the answer is a bit late but if anyone else runs in to this problem:
I had the exact same error message and it was due to malformed resolve
In my case I wrote

```
const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: '',
    component: SomeComponent,
    resolve: SomeResolveService
  }
];
```

But it should be like:

```
const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: '',
    component: SomeComponent,
    resolve: {someProperty: SomeResolveService}
  }
];
```

So I guess removing the extra object should fix the problem:

```
resolve: {
  data:AccountsResolver
}
```

Comment: You are a life saver!